# Can't access the blob file in sub directory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

There is no sub container(directory) in Azure blob storage. I simply use slashes in file name for having virtual sub directory.

here is example.

http://apolyonstorage.blob.core.windows.net/banners/Local/Homepage/index.html

Container Name: banners

File Name : Local/Homepage/index.html

I upload the file and access it on Azure portal but simply accessing the link fail by telling resource is not found but it is actually exist.

Why it fails when i access it on browser by link ?

Comment: What's the ACL on the blob container? For a blob to be accessible directly via URL (or in other words anonymous access, blob container's ACL should be either `Blob` or `Public`.

Comment: Yes the container was private unfortunately. If you can move your comment to answer then i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the ACL on the blob container? For a blob to be accessible directly via URL (or in other words anonymous access, blob container's ACL should be either `Blob` or `Public`.

You can use the sample code below to change the container's ACL:

```
        CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(StorageAccount, StorageAccountKey), true);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("your-container-name");
        BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions()
        {
            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob,//Or BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container
        };
        container.SetPermissions(permissions);
```

Comment: can ACL be set in Azure Portal? I am uploading images to a container. There is not way that I can see to set the Container ACL to `Public` or `Blob`.

Comment: @SeaDude - Yes. Go to storage account -> Containers (under Data Storage) -> Select container -> Click on "Change access level" button. HTH.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! I was previously looking under the `ACL` section.