# Embedding Images which are Stored in Azure BLOB Storage in Website

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to link to or embed images which are stored in an azure BLOB storage container. I don't have any server side programming available, i.e. no C# or PHP, only HTML + JavaScript. Is this possible, and what technologies would you recommend?

I should also mention that my website does not run on the same server and is not running in Azure either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since blob storage is accessible via HTTP protocol, you don't have to do any server side programming. Just ensure that the blob container containing images has `Blob` or `Container` ACL (See this answer of mine: [Can't access the blob file in sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265149/cant-access-the-blob-file-in-sub-directory/28274142#28274142)). After that you just have to use the URL of the image and put that in the `src` attribute of the image and you're done!

So assuming your storage account name is `myaccount` and blob container name is `images` and the image name is `logo.png`, the blob URL would be `[http|https]://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/images/logo.png` and that is something you would put in the src attribute:

```
<img src="[http|https]://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/images/logo.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to leave access permissions private and use JavaScript to download the picture in the background? I don't think I'll be able to modify the ACL of the container.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do so but then you'll need to do some server side programming. Essentially you would have to create a `Shared Access Signature` on the blob container with `Read` permission which would give time bound permission on the images stored in that container.

Comment: I would want the access to be permanent read only. Is there a way to set that up for just one IP (which is running the website)?

Comment: As far as restricting by IP address, it is not possible today. But when you think about it, since the images will be displayed in the browser when a user access your website, essentially every visitor would need access to it and the access will be read-only.